# Can't pass data from one component to another using Service

Tags: angular

The problem is that I can grab data from one component, then pass it to service but another component can't grab that data from this service after.
These components are siblings.

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TodosService {

todo:string = ''

  constructor() { }

  insertTodo(todo: string) {
    this.todo = '' + todo;
    console.log(this.todo)
  }

}
```

Component 1 (Taking data from it)

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { TodosService } from '../todos/todos.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-todo-form',
      templateUrl: './todo-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./todo-form.component.css']
    })
    export class TodoFormComponent {

      constructor(private todosService: TodosService) {}

    todo:string = ''

    submitTodo() {
      this.todosService.insertTodo(this.todo);
      console.log('form ', this.todo)
      this.todo = ''
    }

    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'todo' (input)='submitTodo()'>
```

Component 2 (The one that should get data)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodosService } from '../todos/todos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-list',
  templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-list.component.css']
})
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

todos:string[] = []

  constructor(private todosService: TodosService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  return this.todos.push(this.todosService.todo);
  }

}
```

todos array from the second component is always empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use rxjs Subject

Simplified example:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'

@Injectable()
export class XTestService {

    todo: Subject<string>

    constructor() {
       this.todo = new Subject<string>()
    }

    setTodo(t: string){
        this.todo.next(t)
    }
}
```

In first component you should set your data (I used here dummy string but you can implement it as you want)

Component 1:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { XTestService } from './xtest.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'xtest-cop',
    template: `
   <button type="button" (click)="submitTodo()" >Submit Todo</button>
    `
})

export class XTestComponent {

    constructor(private xservice: XTestService) { }

    submitTodo() {
        this.xservice.setTodo("dummy data")
    }
}
```

And than you should subscribe to todo from your service and wait for data:

Component 2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { XTestService} from './xtest.service'
@Component({
    selector: 'xtest2-cop',
    template: `{{todo}}`
})

export class XTest2Component implements OnInit{

    todo: string

    constructor( private xservice : XTestService){}

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.xservice.todo.subscribe(value => {
            this.todo = value
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could do it much more simply with a getter and not need to use a `Subject`.

Comment: Hi @DeborahK , could you please provide an example with getter. I thought that it would be ok to do this with Subject because those components are siblings. Does getter solution include parent of those two components?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have an example in this blog post: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/ It allows sharing of the data with any component in the application, regardless of its relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that the initialization of your second component, ngOnInit(), is happening before calling method submitTodo(), therefore the value is never going to be pushed into your todo array in the second component.